# How to interpret the periodic phenomenon in learning curve?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, large-data

I am working on training a deep neural network (with pre-training) on millions of data recently. However, I found out that the loss shows a form of periodic phenomenon (about 60000 steps for 1 epoch), as shown below:
[image: loss_vs_updates]
Also, its performance of external evaluation on the validation set was fluctuating, as shown below (higher is better):
[image: eval_vs_updates]

My questions are:

1. What kind of causes can result in such phenomenon?
2. Then what can I do to improve my network?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's not enough information about how the network is constructed to provide a useful answer.

Comment: Two common causes of this behavior are
1. not shuffling the data 
2. setting the learning rate too high